# Как присвоить переменную для целого условия в PERL?

Tags: perl

Есть некий фрагмент кода

```perl
open FILE, '<', $test_txt or die $!;

while (<FILE>) {
    $content = $_;
    if (m/Difference/) {
        print "$diff\n";
    } else {
        if (m/FC:/) {
            print "OK\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Как присвоить этому условию отдельную переменную, для многократного использования этого условия одной переменной ?

Comment: Покажите пример этого "многократного использования", а то не совсем понятно - вы каждый раз хотите условие проверять (тогда вынесите его в функцию) или один раз проверить, а потом выводить результат каждый раз (тогда сохраните результат в переменную, а уже из переменной печатайте).

Comment: и объясните назначение `$content` и `$diff`